# Nginx with SSL behind another Nginx (with nginx-proxy)

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, ssl-certificate-errors, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have two VMS. The first is VM1 and the second is VM2. The first is a VPN server and the second is a client.
On VM1 the Nginx is installed as a reverse proxy from the official Docker repository.
On VM2 the Nginx is installed as a reverse proxy from the [nginx-proxy Docker repository](https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy).
I'm trying to set up an SSL connection from VM1 to VM2 but receiving an error

> curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number

VM1's Nginx config (redirect all queries from 80 and 443 to the VM2)

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  _;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://vm2-client-ip:80;
    }
}

server {
    listen       443;
    listen  [::]:443;
    server_name  _;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://vm2-client-ip:443;
    }
}
```

On the VM2 nginx-proxy generates the next config:

```
# whoami.my-domain.com
upstream whoami.my-domain.com {
    ## Can be connected with "home-network" network
    # who-am-i
    server 10.0.0.2:80;
}
server {
    server_name whoami.my-domain.com;
    listen 80 ;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
    # Do not HTTPS redirect Let'sEncrypt ACME challenge
    location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        auth_basic off;
        auth_request off;
        allow all;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri =404;
        break;
    }
    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
server {
    server_name whoami.my-domain.com;
    listen 443 ssl http2 ;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/whoami.my-domain.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/whoami.my-domain.com.key;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/certs/whoami.my-domain.com.dhparam.pem;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/whoami.my-domain.com.chain.pem;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;
    include /etc/nginx/vhost.d/default;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://whoami.my-domain.com;
    }
}
```

SSL certificates are generated with [this repository](https://hub.docker.com/r/nginxproxy/acme-companion).
Based on logs from this container certificates generates successfully.

An HTTP connection works well.
P.S. If it's a matter both Nginxes works from containers.